How does local compactness imply that $\sigma$-finite measures are Radon?
In section 2.1 (p.11) of the paper The Geometric Foundations of Hamiltonian Monte Carlo, this is the setting:

$Q$ is a positively oriented smooth $n$-manifold (Hausdorff, second-countable, locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$).
Smooth measures on $Q$ are defined as positive, top-rank differential forms on $Q$. (These can be seen to be $\sigma$-finite by writing them as a sum of pushforwards of the Lebesgue-measure, each therefore $\sigma$-finite, over the charts on $Q$.)

Then, the following (slightly paraphrased by me) is stated in passing:
$$
\text{Because $Q$ is locally compact, smooth measures on $Q$ are Radon.   (1)}
$$
The definition of a Radon measure is not given, which is unfortunate given its ambiguity. But I think it's fair to assume it's the most prominent one: inner regularity + local finiteness. In particular, the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani correspondence with linear functionals is established only after this statement, so this could not be the definition here.
My question: The way (1) is phrased suggests that local compactness specifically makes our smooth measures Radon, and it's so easy to see that it requires no further arguments. How so?
